# converting the name of the month into date using R

Tags: r, date

I'm struggling in cleaning a table that has multiple columns

I need to covert the name of the month into a date with dummy day and year
I have tried this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345607/converting-the-name-of-the-month-into-date-using-r) but it didn't work so well.

sample of table

```
> farmDF

       farm            From            To
1 Farmer Market1       June          August
2 Farmer Market2      January       December
3 Farmer Market3     05-01-2013    10-30-2013
4 Farmer Market4       July         November
5 Farmer Market5     06-17-2013    10-14-2013
6 Farmer Market6     05-04-2013    11-23-2013
```

goal

```
> farmDF

       farm            From            To
1 Farmer Market1     06-01-2021    08-01-2021
2 Farmer Market2     01-01-2021    12-01-2021
3 Farmer Market3     05-01-2013    10-30-2013
4 Farmer Market4     07-01-2021    11-01-2021
5 Farmer Market5     06-17-2013    10-14-2013
6 Farmer Market6     05-04-2013    11-23-2013
```

Comment: Please edit your question to specify any code that you may have tried

Comment: In addition it would be easier for the community if you post a `dput` pf you data, or provide an example dataset that mimic your

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function which changes all the values in a column to date. For the example that you have shared this would work :

```
change_to_date <- function(x) {
  #Values that have only characters in them like 'June', 'August' etc
  inds <- grep('^[A-Za-z]+$', x)
  #Add date value
  x[inds] <- paste(x[inds], 1)
  #Change to date class
  lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c('%m-%d-%Y', '%B %d'))
}
```

Apply this function to multiple columns using `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(c(From, To), change_to_date))

#           farm       From         To
#1 FarmerMarket1 2021-01-01 2021-01-01
#2 FarmerMarket2 2021-01-01 2021-01-01
#3 FarmerMarket3 2013-05-01 2013-10-30
#4 FarmerMarket4 2021-01-01 2021-01-01
#5 FarmerMarket5 2013-06-17 2013-10-14
#6 FarmerMarket6 2013-05-04 2013-11-23
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(farm = c("FarmerMarket1", "FarmerMarket2", "FarmerMarket3", 
"FarmerMarket4", "FarmerMarket5", "FarmerMarket6"), From = c("June", 
"January", "05-01-2013", "July", "06-17-2013", "05-04-2013"), 
    To = c("August", "December", "10-30-2013", "November", "10-14-2013", 
    "11-23-2013")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mdy` with `truncated` to return the `Date` class, then we modify those elements having 'year' as `0000` to current 'year' so as to return the **correct**  expected output

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   mutate(across(c(From, To), mdy, truncated = 2),
     across(c(From, To), ~ case_when(year(.) == 0 
            ~  . %m+% years(year(today())), TRUE ~ .)))
#       farm       From         To
#1 FarmerMarket1 2021-06-01 2021-08-01
#2 FarmerMarket2 2021-01-01 2021-12-01
#3 FarmerMarket3 2013-05-01 2013-10-30
#4 FarmerMarket4 2021-07-01 2021-11-01
#5 FarmerMarket5 2013-06-17 2013-10-14
#6 FarmerMarket6 2013-05-04 2013-11-23
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(farm = c("FarmerMarket1", "FarmerMarket2", "FarmerMarket3", 
"FarmerMarket4", "FarmerMarket5", "FarmerMarket6"), From = c("June", 
"January", "05-01-2013", "July", "06-17-2013", "05-04-2013"), 
    To = c("August", "December", "10-30-2013", "November", "10-14-2013", 
    "11-23-2013")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```